# how to use the GvrControllerInput.OnPostControllerInputUpdated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to use the GvrControllerInput.OnPostControllerInputUpdated in unity ?

need to check is it active or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See Here](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/controller-basics#checking_the_controller_status)

You need to check the "state" of the current GVR Controller, which is an Enum inside of the GvrController class itself. Pretty much just make a switch case for checking which state it's in, and run whatever logic you need.

To get the swipe direction, refer to the code below:

```
Vector2 lastTouch;

void Update()
{
  if (GvrController.TouchDown) {
   lastTouch = GvrController.TouchPos;
  }

  if(GvrController.TouchUp){
   Vector2 swipeDirection = GvrController.TouchPos - lastTouch;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brandon,thanks for your input, i am new in this can you please give me a simple sample.

Comment: First, what are you checking the active state of? You want to see if the GvrControllerInput is still active?

Comment: what i need is to find is the left and right swipe of the daydream controller touchpad

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Hi, but this also detect the up and down :-(

Comment: is there any way to get only the x value ?

Comment: Sure, you just check `swipeDirection.X` against `lastTouch.X` and that will give you left/right and right/left motion.